# Basic results in $\sigma$-algebras of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Im struggling to prove a basic fact, my text left this proof to the read but I havent been able to do it.

Let $(X_{n})_{n}$ be a sequence of random variable. Show that $\bigcup_{n\geq 1} \sigma (X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n})$ is an algebra.

Any help would be enormously appreciated <3 thanks so much.

Comment: Are you sure of "union" and should it not be "intersection"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The revised statement is relatively easy to prove after noticing that given any finite collection of events $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^m \in \mathcal{F}$,  where $\mathcal{F}:=\bigcup_{n\geq 1} \sigma (X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n})$, there exists $N$ such that $E_i \in \sigma (X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{N})$ for all $1\leq i\leq m$ , and $\sigma (X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{N})$ is an algebra.

Comment: Thanks so much for your asnwer, I was kinda blocked haha, Can you think in a counter example for F not to be a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: I think any case where $\mathcal{F}\neq \sigma\Big(X_1,X_2,....\Big)$ would work. For example if $X_i$ are all independent and not degenerate, for $E_i=\{  X_i\leq a \}$ then $\cap E_i$ would not be in $\mathcal{F}$.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is not true.

---

E.g. take probability space $(\mathbb Z^2,\wp(\mathbb Z^2),P)$ where $P$ denotes some probability measure.

Let $X:\mathbb Z^2\to\mathbb R$ be prescribed by $(i,j)\mapsto i$.

Let $Y:\mathbb Z^2\to\mathbb R$ be prescribed by $(i,j)\mapsto j$.

Then $\sigma(X)=\{A\times\mathbb Z\mid A\subseteq\mathbb Z\}$ and $\sigma(Y)=\{\mathbb Z\times A\mid A\subseteq\mathbb Z\}$.

Now let $A\subseteq\mathbb Z$ with $A\notin\{\varnothing,\mathbb Z\}$.

Then $(A\times\mathbb Z)\cup(\mathbb Z\times A)\notin\sigma(X)\cup\sigma(Y)$ while it is a union of sets in $\sigma(X)\cup\sigma(Y)$.

This reveals that $\sigma(X)\cup\sigma(Y)$ is not closed under finite unions hence is not an algebra.

Comment: Sorry sir, Im so embarrassed, but I ment to write this "Let $(X_{n})_{n}$ be a sequence of random variable. Show that $\bigcup_{n\geq 1} \sigma (X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n})$ is an algebra." Which is different haha

Comment: Never mind. Ego te absolvo :).